# Redirection with method in Seam

Tags: java, seam

Let's say I have a button:

```
<h:commandButton value="Assign task" action="#{taskAssigner.assignTo(user)}"/>
```

which assigns a new task to a user. I'd like to be able to redirect immediately to the task page, which would be equivalent to clicking on a link like

```
<s:link value="#{task.description}" action="#{workOnTask.start}">
    <f:param name="taskId" value="#{task.id}" />
</s:link>
```

assuming that in WEB-INF/pages.xml I have something like

```
<page view-id="/task-list.xhtml">
    <navigation from-action="#{workOnTask.start}">
        <redirect view-id="/task.xhtml"/>
    </navigation>
</page>
```

I can't see how I can do that in Java in TaskAssigner.assignTo(). I would need access to the Seam component, right? I need to redirect to /task.xhtml and set param taskId as needed and also run workOnTask.start() which does some initialization on the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not recommended to use the `s:link`-tag together with the `action`-attribute (see [JBoss Forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/180334)).

For the navigation issue i would replace (or combine) the `from-action` tag with the `if-outcome` one and return the value behind `if-outcome` at the `assignTo`- and `workOnTask.start`-methods.

```
<page view-id="/task-list.xhtml">
  <navigation>
    <rule if-outcome="navToTask">
      <redirect view-id="/task.xhtml"/>
    </rule>
  </navigation>
</page>
```

And at the method:

```
public String assignTo(User u)
{
    [...]
    // in case of success
    return "navToTask";
}
```

Comment: But how do I connect this to `workOnTask.start`? Is there a way to call it from `assignTo()`? That's the main problem. WorkOnTask has a `@RequestParameter Long taskId` and `WorkOnTask.start()` uses this parameter.

Comment: I guess setting a request-parameter for the next request directly in the method assignTo is not possible.
But if you need the request-parameter to hand-over the task-id, one way would be to set it in the navigation-rule: your component `taskAssigner` has already access to the task - probably you inject it there. So you can use it in the navigation-rule, too:
`<param name="taskId" value="#{task.id}"/>`

Comment: Ok, but how do I make sure that `task` is accessible from pages.xml? The object gets created in the method `assignTo`.

Comment: Outject the new task from the `taskAssigner` using `@Out` with an appropriate scope. But as already indicated you could use the task then directly in the `workOnTask`-component using injection.

Comment: I've injected `taskAssigner` to `WorkOnTask` and added `WorkOnTask.assignAndStart` and called `taskAssigner.assignTo` from there.

Comment: By the way, I have a lot of problems due to some crazy things with Conversations. I hate this framework.